# Is there a way to avoid conversion to glyph paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, svg

I have been playing with tikz lately and I was wondering is there a way to export to svg,
so I have delved into the recent well written [user manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), on page 121 stumble upon:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi example
dvisvgm example
```

Which did a great job!!

But **all shapes** are getting converted to paths, for example (with preamble):

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) ellipse(2cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc(0:180:2); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[teal] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the tex circle and tex rectangle, I would expect it will be converted to
the corresponding SVG elements,
Circle (cx, cy, r)
and
Rectangle (x,y,height,width)

Any suggestions how come? I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Comment: My first question would be: Why is it important to you, how they are imported? And then I guess there are manifold reasons, e.g. I don't know the primitives in PDF, but probably it makes sense that all shapes are converted into paths already in TikZ, because they are easier to handle, as you can apply all sorts of magic to only one data type (path).

Comment: Thank you for the reply,  I was wondering is there a proper way to get a svg without converting to pdf,
or to intervene one of the compilation stages of tex file. cause the original tex file (with tikz) already holds some of the relevant data.

Comment: @JammingThebBits Did you add the `dvisvgm` documentclass option or `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm.def}` to the preamble?  You have to tell PGF to use the `dvisvgm` driver explicitly.  Since `dvisvgm` is used in post-processing there is no way for PGF to detect this automatically during the LaTeX run.

Comment: @JammingThebBits To fix the font problem you will have to tell `dvisvgm` which font format to use.  The default is convert anything ambiguous to paths.  Try instead `dvisvgm --font-format=woff example.dvi`.

Comment: @ Henri Menke Thank you for the help, I have noticed the change after applying your suggestion (it got rid of the `glyph d` ) :) awesome, but unfortunately i'm more concern about the actual shapes which I need their  representation in svg object format (circle, rectangle, ellipse) not in path manner. 
I guess I need to intervene during/ the prepossessing step from tex to pdf because the actual data exist there, It doesn't  bother me to write some python code for parsing this but I'm not familiar with the architecture/flow yet. how can I get better grasp of the underline engine of lualatex?

Comment: dvisvgm converts the data as present in the DVI file. If the shapes are described as paths then this will also be the case in the SVG. dvisvgm doesn't analyze the path data and replaces it by different SVG elements. As a side-note, it's not necessary to use the `dvisvgm` documentclass option. If you omit it, dvisvgm will process the PostScript code generated instead which usually leads to less verbose and more compact SVG files. However, TikZ also uses paths to describe simple geometric shapes in PS mode.

Comment: @JammingThebBits pgf/TikZ uses PDF's graphics model for all its backends, that is, circles are decomposed to arcs, rectangles to closed linear paths. If you want these shapes be expressed by SVG primitives, you will have to do this on your own, using `dvisvgm:raw` or `ps` specials.